# How to dump stdin data in powershell to file?

Tags: linux, ssh, powershell

I'm trying to dump stdin data (file/photos/videos etc) from local (linux/jailed iOS) to remote (Windows) via ssh. In normal situations where local and remote are linux, this works:

```
#! /bin/bash

dest="/var/some/dir"
mkdir $dest
cp /dev/stdin $dest/"name.ext"
```

But now my remote environment changed to Windows 10 (ssh into powershell), simply doing this will dump a corrupted file and I can't open it:

```
$name="somefilename"
$dest="C:\somedir"
mkdir $dest
$input > "$dest\$name.ext"
```

What mistake did I make and how can I fix this? (`scp` and similar tools are out of the equations for linux-windows setup unfortunately since the only way I could pass data around is via stdin due to sandboxed environment - Siri Shortcuts)

Comment: Why out of the equation? All Windows SSH servers come with SFTP and usually SCP.

Comment: That’s because local (iOS) is sandboxed, the only way I could pass the data is via stdin - Siri Shortcuts.

Comment: Hmm, I just successfully used FE Explorer to upload photos via SFTP, on stock iOS...

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success with

```
base64 < local-file | ssh remote-host '"$Input | Set-Content remote-file"'
```

- **This writes a base64-encoded version of the file** because it’s tricky to stop powershell from trying to decode and re-encode the input and change line endings, and so on, but it can do all that to base64-encoded data without mangling the underlying data
- The two levels of quotes `'"…"'` helps powershell get the command as a single string
- This doesn’t do partial transfers on large files